# Unicorns are eating Emacs' daisies

Tags: feature-request, tour

I was pleased, one morning, to read THIS:

[Welcome to Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour)

[image: Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.]

“The human race has only one really effective weapon, and that is laughter. The moment it arises, all our hardnesses yield, all our irritations and resentments slip away and a sunny spirit takes their place.” — Mark Twain

The tone, though not, obviously, the rather frivolous question itself, seems to be an example related to the following question: 
[How does one properly give a higher score to interesting/funny questions?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-does-one-properly-give-a-higher-score-to-interesting-funny-questions)

While I'm waiting for my letter from Hogwarts, what's up with *that*?

I found a similar post here, on serverfault.com:

[About Page example question is “How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies”](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5800/about-page-example-question-is-how-to-prevent-unicorns-from-eating-daisies)

Comment: Is the question asking how to change the "About Page" (which is what Jon answered) or is it asking how to give a higher score to interesting/funny questions?

Comment: // , Is this a question to determine whether Malabarba has a sense of humor? Seriously, it's sort of a "what's up with *that*" sort of question. Why do I only get two options, here, anyway, @Malabarba? Are there, perhaps, no explanations?

Comment: @NathanBasanese, you might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately:

> *There are currently no viable question candidates for the About page*

The most likely reason is that Emacs does not have questions with two answers that are [sufficiently short](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948/1438).

Comment: // , Emacs be cooooommmmplicated.