# How does one properly give a higher score to interesting/funny questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm as serious as the next guy, **when I have to be**, and regrettably, Emacs.stackexchange.com is not a humour site.

Unfortunately, the more seriously I must regard myself, the less serious, sometimes, I feel like I can take other things. Status games, "pissing contests", etc...

Having slowly seen the `Monty` and all other levity bled and racked from `Python`, I would like to know, how does one properly give a higher score to questions' interesting/funny bits?

Please note that this is NOT a question about a specific page, but about the site in general.

Comment: Can you rephrase that in a way that's comprehensible to other people? Are you asking how to upvote a question or what? And will you please stop that `// ,` crap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicorns are eating Emacs' daisies](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/300/unicorns-are-eating-emacs-daisies)

Comment: // , I take it that the question, "How does one properly give a higher score to questions' interesting/funny bits" is incomprehensible to you, Gilles? Is there any specific point of confusion that I could help you on?

Comment: @NathanBasanese: between this question, the "daisies" question, and your comments, I think people may be finding the tone of your posts to be a little off-putting.  Let me suggest that you poke around the site some more to get a feel for what kinds of questions are well-received, and the tone that is the norm around here.

Comment: @NathanBasanese: and yes, please do not use the `//,` prefix you've adopted in your comments.

Answer (score 7):

Emacs.SX is not a humor site.  It is also not a chat site.  These are virtues rather than demerits.

Emacs.SX is Q&A site.  Rather than wax rhapsodic about what makes a good question or answer, let me propose the following rule of thumb for the use of humor in questions, answers, and comments.  Is the signal-to-noise ratio high enough to justify the post?  If yes, the post should be here.  If not, it should not be.

That being said, please consider whether or not an attempt at humor adds to, or detracts from, the value of the post.

Emacs.SX is read by a diverse group of people, so you can be sure that people's senses of humor differ.  I would not want to see people avoid this site because they find the attempts to be funny or edgy to be distasteful.  Also bear in mind that, for a large number of users, English is not their first language.  Please consider the fact that attempts at humor not only may not translate well, but may actually make it more difficult for users to understand a given post.

Short version: if you're going to use humor, use it sparingly.  If you're going to vote on a post, don't do so based on its humor content, but rather based on whether or not its substantive content helps people make better use of Emacs.

Comment: // , 

Please note, in the answer, the "Emacs.stackexchange.com is not a humour site." bit.  
We are all well aware of that. It should not, on the other hand, be unbearably dry and boring. There's plenty of humor, especially visual humor, that may translate well, and actually make it more easy for users to understand a given post. Short version: If you're going to use humor, use humor that you know has translated well in other areas, and that makes the substantive content easier to understand.

Comment: // , Aside from the rather narrow perspective, great anwer, Dan. Very much to the point.

Comment: // , I asked this question for similar reasons to those brought up by Michael Richter: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow#section-9

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in installing the samizdat Zippy yow file, found here http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_zippy.html, and the discussion of the same, linked there.

> "Perhaps it might be an idea to ask the copyright holder on the Zippy comic whether he'd license the current set of lines in a way suitable for
>   Emacs distribution.  Apologies if this has been done already and
>   declined."

As a broader answer, I would assume that questions about specific instances of humor in Emacs are applicable, and they could also brighten people's day.  But questions (or answers) that are just funny for the sake of being funny are likely to be downvoted or flagged for deletion.

I'll also mention: Some posters to help-gnu-emacs have charming wit, and it is good to learn as much as you can from them!

Comment: // , Have you had a chance to read this? http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow#section-9